# If $X, Y$ are jointly standard normal with correlation $r$, and $a, b$ are constants, what is $p(Y < b | X < a)$?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, bivariate

The application here is interpreting the correlation coefficient $r$ in terms of $X$'s ability to predict $Y$ for extreme values of $X$. For example, if $r = .8$, then what is $p(Y < 0 | X < -2)$?

Comment: You need to figure out $P\{Y < b, X < a\}$ in order to compute the desired conditional probability, that is, you need the value of the joint CDF $F_{X,Y}$ at the point $(a,b)$. Unfortunately, there is no closed-form expression for this joint CDF.

Comment: just wanted to point out this (kinda) related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446093/generate-correlated-normal-random-variables given what Dilip said, you may want to try to generate two sequences of correlated samples.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Post as an answer a proof, informal argument, or citation that there is no closed-form solution to the original problem and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: A _proof_ that the joint CDF has no closed-form expression is long but if you are willing to accept the better-known result that there is no closed-form expression for the _univariate_ Gaussian CDF, then you can argue that a closed-form expression for the joint CDF implies a closed-form expression for the univariate CDF since $F_X(x) = \lim_{y\to \infty} F_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Read about _integration in finite terms_ as in for example [this paper](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/courses/mfocs-2012/risch/1995313.pdf) by Risch from Amer. Math. Monthly.

Comment: Note: that a linear combination of bivariate normal distribution is normal (i.e. X is normal and Y is normal) and that $f_{Y|X}=\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$